# how to get User-Agent using easyXDM at server side

Tags: javascript, extjs, cross-browser, javascript-framework

i try with this Eaxmple but it not pass User-Agent to the server

client.html

```
rpc:new easyXDM.Rpc({            
       remote: remoteXDM    // the path to the provider
     },
     {
        remote: {
               login:{}

                }
    }),


Sendrequesttoserver: function(message){

     tricklebot.rpc.login(message,function(response){
        alert(response);
        },
        function(response) {
            alert("Error message : "+response.message);  
        }); 

}
```

server side api.html caode

```
var rpc = new easyXDM.Rpc({},
{
    local: {
        login: function(message, successFn, errorFn){
            serverresponce(message,successFn,errorFn);
        }
        }
});


serverresponce(message,successFn,errorFn){
    Ext.Ajax.request({    
        url: urlhost+'/welcome',     
        method: 'POST',
        jsonData: '{\"message\":\"'+message+'\"}',
        success: function(response, opt) {
            successFn(response);
        },
        failure: function(response, action) {
            errorFn("invalid message");
        } 
    });
}
```

on welcome page url

```
request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

its give null

on welcome page i able to reciver message but not able to recive  request.getHeader("User-Agent");

so how to get User-Agent using easyXDM at server side from Request

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the user agent into the request (so you would then receive it at the end point):

`navigator.userAgent`

Comment: browser not allow to set User-Agent in javascript

Comment: you're right, but you could get it manually from the post request on the server-side... is it the `Ext.Ajax.request()` that isn't sending the user agent?